# Paypal - Sorry, your last action could not be completed

Tags: paypal, payment

Having some (typical) PayPal trouble which I can't seem to fix. I want to know if this issue is actually in PayPal's court and not mine.

So I've enabled "Website Payments Standard" and added all the API details etc etc.

When I select PayPal in the checkout and get fired off to their servers, I log in and get the error saying "Sorry — your last action could not be completed".

I've tried absolutely everything - I've made sure IPN is set up properly, I've removed the details and re-entered them yet it still yields this error.

I have another Magento site set up in a similar fashion which doesn't give me this problem.

Additionally, I just received an email saying "Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are failing:", which is really odd since I'm certain I'm using the correct url.

So I'm kinda hoping this is a quick fix on my end as PayPal, in my experience at least, are horrible at tech support.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, thankfully it's nothing to do with Magento, it was completely PayPal's fault. Apparently someone had added a user email address which caused problems with the account.

So yeah, if you get this error, don't spend too much time scratching your head - get on the phone to PayPal and see if it's not their doing.

Comment: I had to wait 2 days to do so, but I have now :-)